# Heating element in oven not working - can I still use it?

Tags: kitchens, heating, oven

We noticed a few days ago that one of 2 heating elements in the oven is not glowing. I would assume that would mean that for some reason it has stopped working. I did notice recently that whenever I cooked pizza, it would be floppy in the middle. Other foods seem to be okay.

My question is, is the oven still safe to use?

Comment: "Safe" in what sense? Food safety? Electrical safety? Something else?

Comment: I'm unsure how old the oven is as we moved in the house last year. It is an electric oven, with a gas stove above it. I'm just concerned as to whether it is 'safe' electrically. I don't know how long it has been like this for, as I don't tend to look at the heating elements! Hmm.

Comment: Some ovens only use the bottom element for bake and top element for broil. Are there dual elements on the bottom or top with 1 not working? As far as electrical safety it depends on the failure. The heat elements many times fail by shorting out and blowing a hole in the outer metal jacket the other failure can be the connection to the element has failed. If the element has failed it may have taken out the controller. Depending on the type of failure continued usage may cause more damage but the circuit breaker should protect things from being a hazard (breaker tripping stop using until fixed)

Comment: Hi! You have a couple of unregistered accounts. Please [register](/help/why-register) one of them, then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts) and [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: Most likely safe. Post the model # of the oven and then we may be able to track down the specific heating elements and possibly diagnostic information. An individual element can fail and they are generally (but not always) easy to replace, but it could be something else besides the heating element.

Answer (score 1):

I think the oven is *probably* safe electrically, but you should immediately have it repaired. You could "throw parts at the problem" by just replacing the heating element yourself and this might fix it, but it could be something else.

You could remove the element and test its resistance. When our oven went I out I decided to first test the temperature sensor (thermistor). I spent a lot of time on this and the tests indicated it was OK, but testing a heating element might be simpler.

How old is the oven? Is this a stand-alone oven or is it in a stove?

The oven in our GE 30" base quality (but self cleaning) electric range was first erratic and then would not heat. It turned out to be the controller/display module (aka the "oven timer"). The range was over 20 years old and I could not get a new timer module.

I ended up removing and sending the timer to a company (in Ontario, Canada) which repairs them and within a week or 10 days got it back (total charge was about $125). That was 7 years ago and it has worked perfectly since.